# Bind data of custom object to TextView in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

```
   I have one custom object in my ViewModel.I want to bind only one of its member to textview in my droid view.
```

I want to bind only string member of that object to textview
Currently I am doing this.

```
   local:MvxBind = "Text Myobject.ItsMember"
```

Is it ok?
Or am I wrong?

Or Can I do  Like this?

```
   local:MvxBind = "ItemsSource MyObject ; Text ItsMember"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

local:MvxBind = "Text MyObject.ItsMember" is perfectly fine. Just make sure your spelling and capitalization are correct. Also, ItsMember should be a string or have a valid value returned as ToString.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Text MyObject.ItsMember"
        />
```