# MVVMCross Data Binding not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have custom object in my ViewModel.

```
public MyObject PropertyName
{
    get { return _propertyName; }
    set
    {
        _propertyName = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => PropertyName);
    }
}
```

I want to bind only one of its member to textview in my droid view. Found this link:
[Bind data of custom object to TextView in MvvmCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137544/bind-data-of-custom-object-to-textview-in-mvvmcross)
And I am doing exactly like this. local:MvxBind = "Text Myobject.ItsMember"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="LabelCaption" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    local:MvxBind="Text Myobject.ItsMember" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Checked the casing etc. but binding isn't working and I cannot see the string value appearing on the screen while I can print it in the debug window.
Any clues where I may be going wrong?

Comment: Where do you inflate this view?

Comment: [Activity(Label = "MyView")]
    public class MyView : MvxActivity
    {
        protected override void OnViewModelSet()
  {
                    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyView);
  }
    }

Comment: And `Myobject` is the name of the property in your ViewModel?

Comment: MyObject is the type. 
and I bind it using the property name - like this - local:MvxBind="Text PropertyName.Member"

Comment: You can't bind member variables inside of your MyObject, they need to be properties.

Comment: Hey @Cheesebaron, thanks for the comments, but [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137544/bind-data-of-custom-object-to-textview-in-mvvmcross) seems to suggest we can. Just for confirmation, I created a property that was a member of MyObject, and tried to bind directly using the property name. It didn't work either.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't binding the property you have defined in your `ViewModel`, modify your code like this : `local:MvxBind="Text PropertyName.ItsMember"`, Not "Myobject.ItsMember".

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue on my end.

I've tried with:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private MyModel _model; // this is a class member variable or class member field
    public MyModel Model // this is a class member property
    {   
        get => _model;
        set => SetProperty(ref _model, value);
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Model = new MyModel { Name = "Herp" };
    }
}

public class MyModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }
}
```

Then given that `MyViewModel` is DataContext I bind using:

```
local:MvxBind="Text Model.Name"
```

Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to a type.  You need to bind to an instance of the type.  In order for the binding to work the way you have it set in the AXML you need something like

```
public class MyType
{
    private string _ItsMember;
    public string ItsMember
    {
        get
        {
            return _ItsMember;
        }
        set
        {
            _ItsMember = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (()=>ItsMember);
        }
    }
}

private MyType _MyObject;
public MyType MyObject
{
    get
    {
        return _MyObject;
    }
    set
    {
        _MyObject = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(()=>MyObject);
    }
}
```

This arrangement will allow MyObject.ItsMember to resolve to a string property value.  If your property is not a string value, you will have to implement a converter which is a whole 'nother subject.